# Spring-data-mongodb @DBRef causing infinite recursion? I can't work out why

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Ok, so I have a very simple set of Java POJOs in my spring application.

Here is my person class :

```
@Document(collection="people")
public class Person {    

    // Data.
    @Id
    private ObjectId Id;    

    @DBRef
    private List<Entity> entities;    


    /* Getters and setters removed to keep this question simple. */
}
```

And, here is my entity class.

```
@Document(collection = "entities")
public class Entity {    

    @Id
    private ObjectId Id;    

    @DBRef
    private List<Person> people;    

    /* Getters and setters removed to keep question simple. */
}
```

Now, in my spec, "Person" and "Entity" have a Many-Many relationship. A Person can be registered to lots of Entities, and the reverse is true, too.

Now, for some reason, when I try and persist these two, into each other's lists, I get this weird error I have never seen :

```
2017-05-17 23:37:51.966 ERROR 29918 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write content: Infinite recursion (StackOverflowError) (through reference chain: restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"] 

... This continues until the stack overflows. Sorry it is all on one line, wasn't sure how to fix that on this site... it is cut straight from my terminal.
```

What did I do wrong? I have been doing pretty well so far at learning this stack, but I just can't see what is wrong here.

Comment: Yes, definitely this case may occurs. You can handle it by annotating your List<Person> people; & List<Entity> entities;   with @DBRef(lazy = true) instead of @DBRef

Comment: Awesome, thanks, and what IS the actual difference?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 4):

Yes this case can occur!
Consider you have:

```
person1 = {"entities" : ["entity1", "entity2"]}
entity1 = {"persons" : ["person1", "person2"]}
```

So using your above configuration, when spring tries to load "person1", it will load its related "entities(entity1 & entity2)" as well. Now when spring tries to load "entity1", it will again have to load "person1" and so, which definitely leads to Circular dependency/ recursion!

```
restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->restServer.dto.Person["entity"]->restServer.dto.Entity["people"]...
```

So you can handle this by many ways:

### 1. Annotating your lists as lazy:

```
@Document(collection="people")
public class Person {    

    // Data.
    @Id
    private ObjectId Id;    

    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    private List<Entity> entities;    


    /* Getters and setters removed to keep this question simple. */
} 

@Document(collection = "entities")
public class Entity {    

    @Id
    private ObjectId Id;    

    @DBRef(lazy = true)
    private List<Person> people;    

    /* Getters and setters removed to keep question simple. */
}
```

`lazy = true` will prevent Spring from loading un-necessary entities unless you need it(which you can load it by making an explicit call)

### 2. Making list entities as Embedded documents:

```
@Document(collection="people")
public class Person {    

    // Data.
    @Id
    private ObjectId Id;    
    private List<Entity> entities;    


    /* Getters and setters removed to keep this question simple. */
} 

@Document(collection = "entities")
public class Entity {    

    @Id
    private ObjectId Id;    
    private List<Person> people;    

    /* Getters and setters removed to keep question simple. */
}
```

But it totally depends on your requirements.

Comment: I see - and so which is better if I just want these links to manage the relationships between people and entities?

Comment: @IWishIWasABarista use "1. Annotating your lists as lazy:", in second option, there is so much duplication as well as no data integrity

Comment: So wait, do I lose data integrity if I use lazy?

Comment: Unfortunately there is very limited data integrity(as compared to RDBMS) in MongoDb/or other No-SQL databases. And this limited data integrity can only be achieved if you use references(using  @DBRef) irrespective of whether its LAZY or EAGER. In case if you use embedded documents, as I discussed in 2nd point, then there is no data integrity!

Comment: I actually might end up having my own lazy mechanism here, where I just store ID strings, and resolve them when I need to. I never actually need to get the full tree of related items right away.

Comment: then you can use  @DBRef(lazy = true), so if you need later to get it, spring will automatically do it for you

Comment: Hey, I have 2 classes that circularly DBRef each other. (One is a "user" class that I'm interested in) I tried the first method but the `itemResourceRel` endpoint for the user class repository still nesting infinitely. I also tried creating a projection interface for the nested class but that did not work either :( Anything I might be forgetting? (the embedded document option wont work in my architecture sadly)